# How to fetch second row, second column from a .csv file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a CSV file that has looks something like below:

```
Order ID,Order Date,Ship Date,Ship Mode
CA-2011-103800,2013-01-03,2013-01-07 00:00:00,Standard Class
CA-2011-112326,2013-01-04,2013-01-08 00:00:00,Standard Class
```

All I need is to get from first data row the order date, i.e. `2013-01-03` in this case.

I tried the code below which doesn't solve the problem.

```
set file=output.csv
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (%file%) do (echo %%A)
```

I am a beginner. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Append one more line with `:HaveValue` (line with a label) and use `for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (%file%) do set "OrderDate=%%A" & goto HaveValue`. The line assigns the order date to the environment variable `OrderDate` and leaves the loop with a jump to line below the label line `:HaveValue`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done VERY easy by creating an array out of the data from `file.csv`. By using `!Line[2]!` we can grab any line of the `.csv` file we want. Simply change the *Row & Column* configurations to however you need. This can be very useful for searching a `.csv` file.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Row & Column Information
Set "Row=2"
Set "Column=2"

Rem | Turn Lines To Array Strings
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('Type file.csv') do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "Line[!count!]=%%A"
)

Rem | Grab Second Column From Second Row
for /f "tokens=%Column% delims=," %%A in ('Echo !Line[%Row%]!') do (
    set "Data=%%A"
)

Echo Second Row, Second Column Data: %Data%
```

I left a new `Rem` notes to help you along in the script process.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's another alternative.  You can redirect your csv file into a loop containing two `set /P` statements -- one to consume the first line, and the second to set a variable to the second line.  Then for the line that was captured, use variable substring substitution to strip away *, and ,*.

```js
@echo off & setlocal
(
    set /P "="
    set /P "val="
) < "output.csv"

set "val=%val:*,=%"
echo %val:,=&rem;%
```

But really, your attempted solution is *almost* correct.  All that's needed is to break out of the loop after its first iteration.

```js
@echo off & setlocal
set "file=output.csv"
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ("%file%") do echo %%A && exit /b
```

Comment: Hello Rojo, the code worked correctly for the first time. I then tried it for the second time then it isn't giving me the result. It displays nothing actually. Do you have any suggestion for me regarding this?

Comment: @user3775630 As a general means of troubleshooting batch scripts when something isn't behaving as expected, it's a good idea to re-enable command echoing.  Try removing `@echo off` and putting `setlocal` on its own line.  Then run the script again and see whether you can tell at which line the failure occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using `more` command to skip the first line and simply get the second token each time:

to get only the first value:

```
@echo off
set "file=output.csv"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('type order.txt ^| more +1') do echo %%i & goto next
:next
pause
```

or to get each second column's value:

```
@echo off
set "file=output.csv"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('type %file% ^| more +1') do echo %%i
pause
```

Comment: I don't think he/she wants the information after the second+ rows.

Comment: @JohnKens could be, will update my answer with both options.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `skip=1` in the `for` loop options?

Comment: @SomethingDark maybe.. different strokes for different folks?

Comment: Useless use of `type` and `more` when `for /f` is perfectly capable of reading text files and skipping lines without additional commands.

Comment: @rojo As I said earlier, different strokes...? perhaps, also give this a try: `set /p num=select line num to skip: for /f "skip=%num% delims=" %%i in (output.txt) do echo %%i` then give this a try `set /p num=select line num to skip: for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type output.txt ^| more +%num%') do echo %%i` So yes, sometimes there are reasons to methods :)